# Using custom onHover with <figure> in SVG element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, figure

I want to add hover effect from [here](https://tympanus.net/Development/HoverEffectIdeas/index2.html) (Apollo) onto a svg element (or onto pattern used as background for it) that was generated 
by different library (slice of pie menu from [wheelnav.js](http://wheelnavjs.softwaretailoring.net/)).
However, it uses a figure class and I don't know how to implement that onto svg.

Here is the javascript code which creates and implements that background pattern:

```
var patt = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'pattern');
patt.setAttribute('id', 'img1');
patt.setAttribute('patternUnits', 'objectBoundingBox');
patt.setAttribute('width', '1');
patt.setAttribute('height', '1');
patt.setAttribute('x', '0');
patt.setAttribute('y', '0');

var image = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'image');
image.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', 'assets/images/isaac-easy-mode.jpg');
image.setAttribute('width', document.getElementById("wheelnav-piemenu" + 3 + "-slice-" + 0).getBoundingClientRect().width);
image.setAttribute('height', document.getElementById("wheelnav-piemenu" + 3 + "-slice-" + 0).getBoundingClientRect().height);

var defs = document.getElementsByTagName('defs')[0];

patt.appendChild(image);
defs.appendChild(patt);
```

Is there any way to do this? (Doesn't necessary need to use figure class, can be some ghost objects in front of that element or something like that)

Answer (score 0):

Ok i dont know about svg but i think this effect can be achieved using pure css as well without any programming. You can use the `translate` and `transition` properties of css3 to achieve this. Here is a simple sample.

https://codepen.io/Nasir_T/pen/KvmevJ

Hope this give you the idea to work with.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't add div to svg. It would have to be purse css using only that single element that was already created.